# Partially freeze static_map costmap

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, static-map, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

We are using a static costmap with the navigation stack. We update it at 0.2 Hz to keep track of obstacles not present in the bitmap, but... doing that when the robot is not accurately located can make the robot clear obstacles present in the original map loaded from the bitmap.

The question: is there any way to avoid clearing "original" obstacles (those provided by the bitmap)?

Another reason for such modification would be to cope with real obstacles not detectable by the sensors (in our case drops and glass doors), or to limit the areas where we allow the robot to navigate.

Thanks for your help;
kind regards, Jorge

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29840/partially-freeze-static_map-costmap/) by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2284 on 2012-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Very sad to answer my own question one year later...
multi-layered costmaps coming with hydro navi stack do the job perfectly.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-07-29**:
Hi are you navigating with gmapping?? o have you used this before?? because im having some trouble with it and would appreciate some help, thanks

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-08-06**:
what you mean? I use gmapping to create the map, and then amcl to localize the robot on it. That is, the normal use of navi stack.

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-08-08**:
Ok, the thing is im using the navigation stack but with the gmapping online not previously recorded.  Have you used it this way?